# Make an element float to the right inside a div

Tags: html, css

On my product page, there are a number of attributes depending on how many were added to that specific product. It can be from 1 up to 4. The attributes share a common fieldset class name and this is where it gets tricky for me. Basically I'm trying to position 2 of the fieldsets side by side and the rest below them (also side by side). However, I also want them separated and stick to their respective sides within the container. I've managed to make parts of what I said above happen but I have an issue with making the right fieldsets stick to the right side completely. Here's an image description:
[image: Demonstration]

Here's the code so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/26za63sh/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="product_attributes  clearfix">
    <div id="attributes">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">
        <label class="attribute_label" for="group_2">Choose</label>
        <div class="attribute_list">
          <select name="group_2" id="group_2" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
            <option value="81" selected="selected" title="Option #1">Option #1</option>
            <option value="150" title="Option #2">Option #2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">
        <label class="attribute_label" for="group_6">Choose</label>
        <div class="attribute_list">
          <select name="group_6" id="group_6" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
            <option value="31" selected="selected" title="Option #1">Option #1</option>
            <option value="56" title="Option #2">Option #2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">
        <label class="attribute_label" for="group_5">Choose</label>
        <div class="attribute_list">
          <select name="group_5" id="group_5" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
            <option value="80" selected="selected" title="Option #1">Option #1</option>
            <option value="151" title="Option #2">Option #2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#attributes .attribute_list {
  width: 90%;
}

#attributes fieldset {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#attributes fieldset:last-child {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I understand that if I set .attribute_list's width to 100% it will accomplish what I'm trying to do but then the two fieldsets will have no space in the middle. If I instead set a fixed width instead of percentage, then I'll have issues in mobile/tablet view. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. If you want align items in line and float right.

```css
.attribute-container{display:inline-block;}
.attribute_fieldset:nth-child(odd) .attribute-container{float:right;}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

#attributes .attribute_list {
  width: 90%;
}

#attributes fieldset {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

#attributes fieldset:last-child {
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="product_attributes  clearfix">
    <div id="attributes">
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">
      <div class="attribute-container">
      
      
        <label class="attribute_label" for="group_2">Choose 1</label>
        <div class="attribute_list">
          <select name="group_2" id="group_2" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
            <option value="81" selected="selected" title="Option #1">Option #1</option>
            <option value="150" title="Option #2">Option #2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">
      <div class="attribute-container">
      
      
        <label class="attribute_label" for="group_6">Choose 2</label>
        <div class="attribute_list">
          <select name="group_6" id="group_6" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
            <option value="31" selected="selected" title="Option #1">Option #1</option>
            <option value="56" title="Option #2">Option #2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class="attribute_fieldset">
      <div class="attribute-container">
      
     
        <label class="attribute_label" for="group_5">Choose 3</label>
        <div class="attribute_list">
          <select name="group_5" id="group_5" class="form-control attribute_select no-print">
            <option value="80" selected="selected" title="Option #1">Option #1</option>
            <option value="151" title="Option #2">Option #2</option>
          </select>
        </div>
         </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was enough to add an **odd selector** to accomplish what I was trying to do but there's a minor issue now with div class "attribute_label". It's floating to the right but instead of aligning with the fieldset it sticks to the container div. See er-han's fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/er_han/Lprh9zqf/  Any suggestions?

Comment: this is what i updated with my answer. did you check with my answer.

Comment: If I do to this the original issue comes back: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4kW5.png

Comment: Oh never mind. Since there was no width property in the new attribute-container you added, all the fieldsets were different sizes so I didn't notice your solution actually worked until I added it. Thanks!

Comment: No need to set display:inline-block for new div(attribute-container). Its only used to hold the child elements without affect child alignment. Thats it. You done.  Glad to help .! welcome

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the elements in `fieldset` all float to left.

Add this to float the inner elements of **odd fieldsets** to right:

```
#attributes fieldset:nth-child(odd) * {
  float: right;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/er_han/Lprh9zqf/